# Ordering posts by title containing numbers

Tags: order

I’m looking for help using the posts_orderby hook in wordpress.
Please forgive the low level of abstraction, but I really need quick help on this.
I have custom type posts whose titles are made up of a fixed 8-character text string (TM.74.G.) followed by numbers ranging from  358 to above 1000 (and that’s the order I need them to follow). As expected, sorting in ASC returns a post order which starts from 1000 (titles are not processed as integers); if I apply a filter like this

```
function orderby_post_title_int( $orderby )
{ return ‘(wp_posts.post_title+0) ASC’; }
```

results are unclear.
Any hint on this? Thank in advance, Alessio

Comment: Try `return "SUBSTRING( wp_posts.post_title, 9 ) + 0 ASC";`.. which should work if the post title is always in the form of `TM.74.G.<number>` like `TM.74.G.358` and `TM.74.G.1000`. And note that you should conditionally apply your filter because `posts_orderby` is run on many pages, including on the admin side, e.g. the "Posts" page (e.g. at `wp-admin/edit.php`).

Comment: Dear Sally, your solution works a charm. there's actually a small typo (it's "substr(…)", not "SUBSTRING(…)); if you answer the question, I'll mark it duly answered. You really made my day, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help, but actually, that wasn't a typo.. and (at least in MySQL), `SUBSTR()` and `MID()` are synonyms for `SUBSTRING()`.. [demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4xkPYacc6YLxWLeQGGzXH7/0) :) Anyway, I've just posted an answer and hopefully the "rants" (or additional notes/info) would help you more.. ;)

Comment: Dear Sally, you were right all the way. I would kindly ask you to help a little more on this: 
1. how can I keep this order in **previous post** - **next post links** from each single custom post?
2. If some titles **are not integers** (i.e.TM.74.G.**IIC**), how can I keep the above order for the integer title post and then display the non-integer ones in ASC alphabetical order? Is this possible at all? Third and last, would it work with Roman Numerals?

Thank you in advance for any help you will provide!!!

Comment: Hi @AlessioBaccarini. As for the 3rd one (sorting by Roman numerals), I'm not sure - maybe it's possible, but wouldn't be an easy task. Nonetheless, please consider posting new questions (one for each the 3 questions in your previous comment) and then include as much details as possible in your question.

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ, I have extended this thread [in a new question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/404109/custom-ordering-fails-after-ajax-post-filter). 

I'd really appreciate it if you could take a look at it!

Thanks in advance, Alessio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is a generic (My)SQL question, but anyway, as I already said in my comment, if the post title is **always** in the form of `TM.74.G.<number>` like `TM.74.G.358` and `TM.74.G.1000`, then you can use the [`SUBSTRING()` function in MySQL/MariaDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to firstly extract the `<number>` value (e.g. `358`) and then sort the posts by that number.

So in your filter function, just replace the `return` part with:

```php
return "SUBSTRING( wp_posts.post_title, 9 ) + 0 ASC";
```

---

Now here's something specific to WordPress: You should ***conditionally** apply your filter* because [`posts_orderby`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/) is run on many pages like category archive pages, search results pages, single post pages, etc., including on the admin side, e.g. the "Posts" page (e.g. at `wp-admin/edit.php`), so you wouldn't want to mess with the posts' sorting on those pages, right?

Secondly, instead of hard-coding the table *prefix* (which defaults to `wp_`), you should use `$wpdb->prefix` like so `{$wpdb->prefix}posts`, but for core tables, they are actually available as public properties in the `wpdb` class, so for example the posts table, you could use `$wpdb->posts` to reference that table.

```php
global $wpdb; // don't forget to declare the $wpdb global
return "SUBSTRING( $wpdb->posts.post_title, 9 ) + 0 ASC";
```

And here's an example of how can you conditionally apply your filter:

```php
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_posts_orderby', 10, 2 );
// **Replace "foo" with the correct post type.
function my_posts_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
    // Check if it's *not* the main query (which runs automatically on page load).
    // And if it's not, then do nothing.
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return $orderby; // always return it :D
    }

    // 1. Apply the filter if we're on the "foo" post type archive.
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'foo' ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        return "SUBSTRING( $wpdb->posts.post_title, 9 ) + 0 ASC";
    }

    // 2. Or if we're on the admin page for managing the CPT's posts.
    if ( is_admin() && 'edit-foo' === get_current_screen()->id ) {
        global $wpdb;
        return "SUBSTRING( $wpdb->posts.post_title, 9 ) + 0 ASC";
    }

    return $orderby;
}
```