# Custom ordering fails after AJAX post filter

Tags: ajax, mysql, order

With the invaluable help of a fellow developer (nicknamed SallyCJ), I have managed to order custom type posts by the last 'word' of their titles (integers ranging from 358 to above 1000). I have applied the below filter

```php
function orderby_post_title_int( $orderby ){
    return "SUBSTRING( wp_posts.post_title, 9 ) + 0 ASC";
}
```

and it works like a charm. Please note titles have a fixed 8-character string (TM.74.G.) coming before the integer that provides the order, hence the `"SUBSTRING( wp_posts.post_title, 9 ) + 0 ASC";`

Yet, after AJAX filtering the custom posts by categories and subcategories, posts are listed up to TM.74.G.**999**, skipping all following posts ranging from TM.74.G.**1000** to TM.74.G.**1033**.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('submit','[data-js-form=filter]',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var tabClass = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('class').split(' ')[0];
            //alert(tabClass);
            var data = $(this).serialize(); 
            // console.log(data);
    
        $('.' + tabClass + ' ' +'.js-filter').toggleClass('hasloader');
        $.ajax({
            url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl,
            //data: { action: 'filter', category: category },
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(data);
                //alert('ok');
                 $('.' + tabClass + ' ' +'.js-filter').toggleClass('hasloader');
                 $('.' + tabClass + ' ' +'.js-filter').html(result);
                //alert('ok');
                // console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.warn(result);
                
                 $('.' + tabClass + ' ' +'.js-filter').toggleClass('hasloader');
            }
        })
    })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

php callback:

```
<?php add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function'); // wp_ajax_{ACTION HERE} 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');

function misha_filter_function(){
    add_filter('posts_orderby', 'orderby_post_title_int' );
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         =>  'intaglioligneo',
        'posts_per_page'    =>  -1
        
    );
 if( isset( $_POST['freesearch'] ) ) {
    $args['s'] = $_POST['freesearch'];
 }
    // for taxonomies / categories
    if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
            )
        );
        elseif( !isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
        $args = array(
            'post_type'         =>  'intaglioligneo',
            'posts_per_page'    =>  -1
            
        );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
             
            include(locate_template('template-variables.php')); 
            include(locate_template('template-card.php'));
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo '<h3>Nessuna scheda trovata</h3>.<p class="has-drop-cap is-style-hero2"> Non ci sono schede che rispondano ai criteri di ricerca impostati dall\'utente; si prega di riprovare calibrando diversamente i filtri di categoria e/o sottocategoria, oppure di controllare il testo inserito nel campo \'Ricerca Libera\'.</p>';
    endif;
    
    die();
}
```

Please note that if I remove the custom ordering all posts are filtered and rendered correctly.

Any hint?

Thanks in advance for you help,

Alessio

Comment: can you update your question to include the full code? There's very little context, e.g. what hook is `orderby_post_title_int` used on and where is this code located? And where is the AJAX code you're having issues with? Is there a reason you chose to use the old legacy admin AJAX API instead of the REST API for your AJAX requests?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @TomJNowell!

'Is there a reason you chose to use the old legacy admin AJAX API instead of the REST API for your AJAX requests?'

No specific reason; please find code in the updated post

Comment: @AlessioBaccarini `SUBSTRING( wp_posts.post_title, 9 ) + 0` will not skip 1000 and up. In fact, even if the 9th and up characters are not digits, MySQL will still not skip the rows, but they're put at the top when ASC is the sort order. [Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n6LdUwAoeBBfQ2RHHdzUYa/0)

Comment: And your AJAX PHP callback is OK, except that - 1) I don't think you need the `elseif` part which overrides the entire args array; 2) Your `tax_query` should use `'field' => 'term_id'`, i.e. use `term_id` and not `id`; 3) You should use `get_template_part()` instead of `include(locate_template())`; 4) In WordPress, it's recommended to use `wp_die()` instead of `die()`; and 5) You shouldn't hard-code the table name (`wp_posts`).

Comment: Also, an aside - even if you're not going to use it today, you should still read the [REST API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) and learn what the REST API is, what it does (or its purposes) and what can one use it for.